# Need a Gui Keypad for a touchscreen that outputs a pin when code is correct

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, touchscreen, keypad

I have a raspberry pi with a touchscreen running raspbian, I'm hoping to have a Gui on the touchscreen that had a number keypad that when a correct input is entered a pin will output to a door latch or something. I have been over to make a Gui with a number on (by Python) it but i cant get several numbers to sit next to each other. any info will help on this thanks :)
This is the code I used to try and place the buttons (you can see i just used a simple LED on/off button Gui and used it to see the placement of the buttons)

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(40, GPIO.LOW)

win = Tk()

myFont = tkFont.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 36, weight = 'bold')

def ledON():
    print("LED button pressed")
    if GPIO.input(40) :
        GPIO.output(40,GPIO.LOW)
                ledButton["text"] = "LED OFF"
    else:
        GPIO.output(40,GPIO.HIGH)
                ledButton["text"] = "LED ON"

def exitProgram():
    print("Exit Button pressed")
       GPIO.cleanup()
    win.quit()  


win.title("LED GUI")


exitButton  = Button(win, text = "1", font = myFont, command = ledON, height     =2 , width = 8) 
exitButton.pack(side = LEFT, anchor=NW, expand=YES)

ledButton = Button(win, text = "2", font = myFont, command = ledON, height = 2, width =8 )
ledButton.pack(side = TOP, anchor=CENTER, expand=YES)

ledButton = Button(win, text = "3", font = myFont, command = ledON, height = 2, width =8 )
ledButton.pack(side = RIGHT, anchor=NE, expand=YES)

ledButton = Button(win, text = "4", font = myFont, command = ledON, height = 2, width =8 )
ledButton.pack(side = TOP, anchor=W, expand=YES)

ledButton = Button(win, text = "5", font = myFont, command = ledON, height = 2, width =8 )
ledButton.pack(side = TOP, anchor=W, expand=YES)

ledButton = Button(win, text = "6", font = myFont, command = ledON, height = 2, width =8 )
ledButton.pack(side = TOP, anchor=W, expand=YES)

ledButton = Button(win, text = "7", font = myFont, command = ledON, height = 2, width =8 )
ledButton.pack(side = TOP, anchor=W, expand=YES)

ledButton = Button(win, text = "8", font = myFont, command = ledON, height = 2, width =8 )
ledButton.pack(side = TOP, anchor=W, expand=YES)

ledButton = Button(win, text = "9", font = myFont, command = ledON, height = 2, width =8 )
ledButton.pack(side = TOP, anchor=N, expand=YES)

ledButton = Button(win, text = "0", font = myFont, command = ledON, height = 2, width =8 )
ledButton.pack(side = TOP, anchor=NW, expand=YES)



mainloop()
```

Comment: show your code - what did you use - Tkinter, PyQt, wxPython or something other ?

Comment: I think its Tkinter

Comment: you can assign to every button function with argument - ie. `command=lambda:ledON("1")` and use `def ledON(arg):` to get this argument and remember on list. This way you can get your PIN.

Comment: BTW: you can use `grid(row=0, column=0)` instead of `pack()`

Comment: Thanks for the Grid suggestion, Ive created a code that makes a nice gui and it prints what you have pressed but I'm still a bit stumped on how to collect the data and create an output if the 4 number input matches the correct code or clear it if its incorrect,

Comment: Heres my code so far...

Comment: `code`
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont
root = Tk()
size = tkFont.Font(size = 40)


def Code1():
        print("1")
        
def Code2():
        print("2")

def Code3():
        print("3")

def Code4():
        print("4")

def Code5():
        print("5")

def Code6():
        print("6")

def Code7():
        print("7")

def Code8():
        print("8")

def Code9():
        print("9")

def Code0():
        print("0")

def CodeC():
        print("Cancel")

def CodeSubmit():
        print("Submit")

Comment: root.title("KeyPad")

button = Button(root, text='1', bg='lightblue', font = size, command = Code1)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

button = Button(root, text='2', bg='lightblue', font = size, command = Code2)
button.grid(row=0, column=1)

button = Button(root, text='3', bg='lightblue', font = size, command = Code3)
button.grid(row=0, column=2)

button = Button(root, text='4', bg='lightblue', font = size, command = Code4)
button.grid(row=1, column=0)

button = Button(root, text='5', bg='lightblue', font = size, command = Code5)
button.grid(row=1, column=1)

Comment: button = Button(root, text='6', bg='lightblue', font = size, command = Code6)
button.grid(row=1, column=2)

button = Button(root, text='7', bg='lightblue', font = size, command = Code7)
button.grid(row=2, column=0)

button = Button(root, text='8', bg='lightblue', font = size, command = Code8)
button.grid(row=2, column=1)

button = Button(root, text='9', bg='lightblue', font = size, command = Code9)
button.grid(row=2, column=2)

button = Button(root, text='0', bg='lightblue', font = size, command = Code0)
button.grid(row=3, column=1)

Comment: button = Button(root, text='C', bg='red', font = size, command = CodeC)
button.grid(row=3, column=0)

button = Button(root, text='>', bg='green', font = size, command = CodeSubmit)
button.grid(row=3, column=2)

root.mainloop()

Comment: sorry about spreading it across several posts im not yet sure how to put it all in one :P

Comment: comment in not good place for code - you can edit question and add your code.

Comment: you can define one function `def Code(value): print(value)` and assign to buttons like `command=lambda:Code("2")`, `command=lambda:Code("3")`

Comment: create global/external list `pin = []` and inside `Code(value)` do `pin.append(value)` and you will have all numbers on the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple example with keypad:

I use global string variable `pin` to keep all pressed numbers.
(You can use `list` instead of `string`)

Key `*` removes last number, key `#` compares `pin` with text `"3529"`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def code(value):

    # inform function to use external/global variable
    global pin

    if value == '*':
        # remove last number from `pin`
        pin = pin[:-1]
        # remove all from `entry` and put new `pin`
        e.delete('0', 'end')
        e.insert('end', pin)

    elif value == '#':
        # check pin

        if pin == "3529":
            print("PIN OK")
        else:
            print("PIN ERROR!", pin)
            # clear `pin`
            pin = ''
            # clear `entry`
            e.delete('0', 'end')

    else:
        # add number to pin
        pin += value
        # add number to `entry`
        e.insert('end', value)

    print("Current:", pin)

# --- main ---

keys = [
    ['1', '2', '3'],    
    ['4', '5', '6'],    
    ['7', '8', '9'],    
    ['*', '9', '#'],    
]

# create global variable for pin
pin = '' # empty string

root = tk.Tk()

# place to display pin
e = tk.Entry(root)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, ipady=5)

# create buttons using `keys`
for y, row in enumerate(keys, 1):
    for x, key in enumerate(row):
        # `lambda` inside `for` has to use `val=key:code(val)` 
        # instead of direct `code(key)`
        b = tk.Button(root, text=key, command=lambda val=key:code(val))
        b.grid(row=y, column=x, ipadx=10, ipady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

GitHub: [`furas/python-examples/tkinter/__button__/button-keypad`](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/__button__/button-keypad)

(**EDIT:** I changed link to GitHub because I moved code to subfolder)

Comment: that link doesn't work anymore ? do you have more keypad examples?

Comment: @sunny_old_days remove `button-keypad` from link and you get all my tkinter's examples on GitHub. If you remove also `tkinter` then you get all my Python's examples on GitHub.

Comment: @sunny_old_days I add new link to this code on GitHub because I moved it to subfolder.